# Appropriate sampling frequency for bpsk modulated signal

Tags: digital-communications, dsp-core

I'm modulating a message with particular baudrate, say 2MHz using BPSK , Carrier frequency(Fc) is 8MHz, What should be appropriate Sampling Frequency(Fs) following Nyquist criteria, Should it be greater than 2*(2*baudrate) or 2*(Fc+baudrate)?

Comment: Are you talking about generating or receiving the signal?

Comment: I'm talking about generating.

Comment: That really depends on your hardware, doesn't it?  If the system is supposed to directly generate a signal with 8MHz center frequency, then you'll need the output sampling rate to be $2 \times (F_c + \mathrm{baudrate}) $ or so. If you have some analog way of up-shifting the frequency, then you could just output the sampled data at the first rate. What hardware do you have available?

Answer (score 1):

The sampling frequency depends not only on the carrier frequency and the symbol (baud) rate, but also on the pulse shape. If you transmit with square pulses, you'll need a very large bandwidth (in theory, infinite). If you transmit with sinc pulses, then the base-band bandwidth is half the pulse rate. Other pulses will fall somewhere in between.

To expand on Peter K.'s comment: you should look into using the complex envelope for simulation. The advantage is that, when you use it, the sampling frequency depends only on the symbol rate and pulse shape, not on the carrier frequency.